# filter with instanceOf Tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find the co-occurrence of words. Following is the code I am using.

```
val dataset = df.select("entity").rdd.map(row => row.getList(0)).filter(r => r.size() > 0).distinct()
println("dataset")

dataset.take(10).foreach(println)
```

**Example Dataset**

```
dataset
[aa]
[bb]
[cc]
[dd]
[ee]
[ab, ac, ad]
[ff]
[ef, fg]
[ab, gg, hh]
```

**Code Snippet**

```
case class tupleIn(a: String,b: String)
case class tupleOut(i: tupleIn, c: Long)
val cooccurMapping = dataset.flatMap(
list => {
    list.toArray().map(e => e.asInstanceOf[String].toLowerCase).flatMap(
        ele1 => {
            list.toArray().map(e => e.asInstanceOf[String].toLowerCase).map(ele2 => {
                if (ele1 != ele2) {
                    ((ele1, ele2), 1L)
                }
            })
        })
})
```

How to filter from this?

I have tried

```
.filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[(String, String), Long]])
```

> :121: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type Unit cannot also be a ((String, String), Long)
>              .filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[(String, String), Long]])
>                                         ^
>
> :121: error: isInstanceOf cannot test if value types are references.
>              .filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[(String, String), Long]])

```
.filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[tupleOut])
```

> :122: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type Unit
>   cannot also be a coocrTupleOut
>              .filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[tupleOut])
>                                         ^ :122: error: isInstanceOf cannot test if value types are references.
>              .filter(e => e.isInstanceOf[tupleOut])

If I map

```
.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[Tuple2[(String, String), Long]])
```

The above snippet works fine but gives this exception after sometime:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast
>   to scala.Tuple2   at
>   $line84834447093.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$9.apply(:123)
>     at
>   $line84834447093.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$9.apply(:123)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Why is `instanceOf` not working in `filter()` but working in `map()`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? This looks like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Generally speaking you shouldn't have to use either `asInstanceOf` or `isInstanceOf` too often (or ever) when using Scala and Spark...

Comment: @TzachZohar I am trying to create the cooccurance mapping for the list of words to create Grapg in graphframes. The code am taking help from is https://github.com/Yachironi/twitter-mining/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dk/twitterMining/TwitterMining.scala#L69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your code is collection of items of type Unit so both the filter and map iterate nothing (note that map does *as* so it will cast to the type you want wheres as is checks the type)

In any event, if I understand your intent correctly you can get what you want with spark's built in functions:

```
val l=List(List("aa"),List("bb","vv"),List("bbb"))
val rdd=sc.parallelize(l)
val df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd,"data")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ndf=df.withColumn("data",explode($"data"))
val cm=ndf.select($"data".as("elec1")).crossJoin(ndf.select($"data".as("elec2"))).withColumn("cnt",lit(1L))
val coocurenceMap=cm.filter($"elec1" !== $"elec2")
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am trying to achieve this without using dataframe API of spark.

Comment: As I told you both your map and filter get list of Unit (BoxedUnit which you see in the exception) and not tuples. Also when you get it to work it would be less efficient than the code above